# Collision Detection C++ Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm developing a simple collision engine in c++ intended to be used with SFML. I looked at some tutorials and came to the conclusion that the SAT would be more than enough for my plans and started implementing. It seems to work partly. When testing it, the vector for shortest way outside only seems to be correct sometimes. [Here's an image showing all outcomes on two polygons](http://prntscr.com/788n8g).

Here's my functions that are part of the collision detection.

```
Range::Range(float mi, float ma) :
    min(mi), max(ma) {
}

Range Range::overlap(Range other) {
  Range r;
  r.min = min > other.min ? min : other.min;
  r.max = max < other.max ? max : other.max;
  return r;
}

Range CollisionShape::project(sf::Vector2f axis) {
  float d = dot(_vertices_t[0], axis);
  Range r(d, d);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < _num_vertices; i++) {
    d = dot(_vertices_t[i], axis);
    r.min = d < r.min ? d : r.min;
    r.max = d > r.max ? d : r.max;
  }
  return r;
}

sf::Vector2f CollisionShape::sat(CollisionShape& other, bool own) {
  sf::Vector2f ret;
  bool first = true;
  // Separating Axis Theorem
  unsigned num = own ? _num_vertices : other._num_vertices;
  sf::Vector2f* vertices = own ? _vertices_t : other._vertices_t;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    sf::Vector2f v = normalize(vertices[(i + 1) % num] - vertices[i]);
    sf::Vector2f n(v.y, -v.x);
    Range r1 = project(n);
    Range r2 = other.project(n);
    if (r1.max < r2.min || r1.min > r2.max) {
      return sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    }
    Range overlap = r1.overlap(r2);
    if (first || (overlap.max - overlap.min) < length(ret)) {
      ret = -n * (overlap.max - overlap.min);
      first = false;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

sf::Vector2f CollisionShape::collision(CollisionShape& other) {
  // Test shape's potential separating axes
  sf::Vector2f ret1 = sat(other, true);
  if (ret1 == sf::Vector2f(0, 0)) {
    return ret1;
  }
  // Test other shape's potential separating axes
  sf::Vector2f ret2 = sat(other, false);
  if (ret2 == sf::Vector2f(0, 0)) {
    return ret2;
  }
  return (length(ret1) < length(ret2) ? ret1 : ret2);
}
```

I just can't see where the problem could be.
BIG EDIT: Well I kinda see the connection. Seems like the vectors are wrong if they are along the x or y axis (contain a 0 for one element). Still don't really know how this happens.

Comment: You might want to clean up your code. The `collision` function has two blocks which are essentially identical and could easily be extracted into a function to get rid of the code duplication.

Comment: Yeah that's only there atm and will be cleaned up later. But the priority is to get it work..

Comment: Shorter code is easier to debug. Have you produced a test case to show the faulty behavior? You don't give us much to go on here.

Comment: Yes I know. I've added links to screenshots for both of the described scenarios.

Comment: there is no excuse for not extracting identical code to a function. absolutely none. without knowing the definition of Range there is some copy-paste code that is highly suspicious.

Comment: alright, fine.. edited OP, doubt it will change anything though.

Comment: i bet it will. i can't guarantee it works but at least one big error is gone.

Comment: From the image it seems it goes wrong when one side of the green polygon lies completely within the red polygon.

Comment: some more hints: 
`sat` is symmetrical so avoid `own` but do `this->sat(other)` and `other.sat(*this)`. 
also have a look at `std::min`. 
implement a `Range::length()`. 
implement a `Range Range::extend(float)`. 
implement a `bool Range::does_overlap()` (or implement negative overlap lengths). 
your `Range::overlap` will return an inverted range if not overlapping i.e. contradicting the naming min/max. with naming first/second and negative length this might be a concept. 
never ever name a variable `ret`, give it a meaningful name. 
write for human readability (yourself, next maintainer, ...)

Comment: Range::overlap won't return an inverted range in this case, since the function returns if Ranges don't overlap. I see where you're coming from and ik the code could be nicer but it's not part of the problem